# How do I create a macro that changes the cell displayed by pressing the button?

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc, vba

Example. In cell B1 display the contents of cell A1. And by pressing the button I wish to cell B1 displays the value of cell A2, and press the button again I wish to cell B1 displays the contents of cell A3 and so to cell A100. Can someone help me? This is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning below code to button

```
Sub DISPLAY_CELLS()
    Range("C1") = (Range("C1") mod 100) + 1
    Range("B1") = Range("A" & Range("C1"))
End Sub
```

This will move you down to 100th data everytime you click button

THen start over when it reaches 100th data

Range("C1") is used to find Nth data.